# Unable to see activity log in custom object

Tags: related-list, activities, app

I am VERY new to salesforce.I feel like I have moved to a foreign county and trying to learn the language (without a translator).  We are using a program (App) that has pre-developed "Custom Object" (tabs).  On the bottom of one of the objects I need to able to enter activities.                                                                                (1) When I go into Create/Object/Custom Objects I can see the object.  When I click on edit, "Allow activities" is checked.
(2) When I select the object and go to Page Layout, I see three sections at the bottom (a) Open activities (b) notes and attachments and (c) activity history.

When I open the tab, none of those appear.  None of those sections are visible. What am I doing wrong.  Help

Answer (score 1):

The related lists are not in your configuration for that object. Edit the layout, re-order the related lists, click "Save," and when the "Override Users' Related List Customizations" appears, click "Yes." All users will now see the related lists.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I was not sure what you meant by re-order but we removed them and put them back on the page layout.  We also changed their order on the page.  We hit save and followed your directions for the over-ride response.  I still do not see them except for on the page-layout.  Do you have anything else I can try?

Comment: The only other probable cause I can think of is that the page is actually a Visualforce override, which means you'd have to update the code. Can you post the URL you see in your browser's address bar when you are viewing a record?

Answer (score -1):

1) since the "Allow activities" is checked you can see the open activities, to see activity history you need to check **"Track Field History"** on the objects "Optional Features" section. setup--> create--> objects--> (custom object name) --> all way at the bottom you can see optional features

Check to see if the related lists are enabled for the page layout:

This is what I mean when I say check the related list :

go to any record in the object and click on "edit layout" and in the related list section you can see that the approval history and the notes and attachments will be bold( meaning they are not included in the pagelayout for the user)

Comment: Track Field History isn't Activity History.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes you are right, my bad misguiding the user on the activity history, mixed up activity history with track history, activity history gets filled only when the user selects track history on the field !!! I was in a hurry to grab points and I GOT SERVED :-/

Comment: The Notes and Attachment section, Open Activities, and Activity History are all in bold.  When we look at the related lists section, they are greyed out.  We added Activity History, but it to is in bold and doesn't show up when we open the main tab for that object.